# how to keep text orientation unchanged during rotation in SVG

Tags: html, svg, rotation

I am using `<g transform = "rotate(45, 10, 30)">` in `svg` to roate som circles and texts around a point at the same time, however, I want to keep orientation of each individual font the same (e.g., always facing one direction while the text is moved/rotated).

For example,how could I change the labels such as "A" in  the right-side image to correct orientation after rotation? 
[image]

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: rotate but keep same orientation? that's somewhat of a contradiction: "Change it, but don't change it".

Comment: Use the rotate attribute on the text element to rotate each glyph in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rotation of `<g>roup` and reverse rotation of the text within it, try this alternate grouping. Center the `<g>` around `origin(0,0)` with negative `x=` and `y=` values & use `rotate(degree, 0, 0)` on `circle_group`, then `translate(x,y)` on the `main_group`.

Edit: Here's an animated example, modified from this [source](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/svg/svgAnimation/basic/02scriptSquare.html). The trick is to move it around the origin with sin() and cos() trigonometric functions.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>  
    <title>JavaScript SVG Animation</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> <!-- Remove this line in production. -->
    </head>

    <body>
    <svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
    <g transform="translate(400, 400)"> <!-- Create a Cartesian coordinate system (with the y-axis flipped) for the animated square. That is, place the origin at the center of the 800 x 800 SVG viewport: -->

        <!-- A 200 x 200 square with the upper left-hand corner at (-100, -100). This places the center of the square 
        at the origin (0, 0): -->  
        <rect id="mySquare" x="-100" y="-100" width="200" height="200" rx="5" ry="5" 
            style=" fill: yellow; stroke: yellow; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 10, 5;" />
            
        <!-- Represents the x-axis: -->
        <line x1="-400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" style="stroke: blue;" /> 

        <!-- Represents the y-axis (although up is negative and down is positive): -->  
        <line x1="0" y1="-400" x2="0" y2="400" style="stroke: blue;" /> 
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="141" fill="none" stroke="yellow"/>           
        <g id="circle_a">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>
          <text x="-5" y="5" width="20" height="20">A</text>
        </g>
        <g id="circle_b">
           <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
            <text x="-5" y="5" width="20" height="20">B</text>
        </g>
    </g>

    </svg>
    <script>
    "use strict";

    /* CONSTANTS */
    var initialTheta = 0; // The initial rotation angle, in degrees.
    var thetaDelta = 0.3; // The amount to rotate the square about every 16.7 milliseconds, in degrees.
    var angularLimit = 180; // The maximum number of degrees to rotate the square.
    var theSquare = document.getElementById("mySquare");
    var circleA = document.getElementById("circle_a");
    var circleB = document.getElementById("circle_b");

    theSquare.currentTheta = initialTheta; // The initial rotation angle to use when the animation starts, stored in a custom property.

    var requestAnimationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(doAnim); // Start the loop.
    function doAnim() {
      if (theSquare.currentTheta > angularLimit) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameID); // The square has rotated enough, instruct the browser to stop calling the doAnim() function.
        return; // No point in continuing, bail now.
      }

      theSquare.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + theSquare.currentTheta + ")"); // Rotate the square by a small amount.
      circleA.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" +Math.cos((theSquare.currentTheta-45)*Math.PI/180)*141 + "," + Math.sin((theSquare.currentTheta-45)*Math.PI/180)*141+")"); // Move the circle A
      circleB.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" +Math.cos((theSquare.currentTheta+45)*Math.PI/180)*141 + "," + Math.sin((theSquare.currentTheta+45)*Math.PI/180)*141+")"); // move the circle B
      theSquare.currentTheta += thetaDelta;  // Increase the angle that the square will be rotated to, by a small amount.
      requestAnimationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(doAnim); // Call the doAnim() function about 60 times per second (60 FPS), or about once every 16.7 milliseconds until cancelAnimationFrame() is called.
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Note: This animation is tested on latest Chrome, FF and IE11 (July 2014). Doesn't work on IE9.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure SVG

1. Rotate the entire group of elements: triangle, spiral and colored circles with the letters

```
<g id = "common"`>
 ....
</g> 
<animateTransform xlink:href="#common"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  begin="svg1.click"
  restart="whenNotActive"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
  dur="10s"
  values="
       0, 75.74, 74.91;
      -360, 75.74, 74.91"
  additive="sum" />
```

2. Inside is the second animation of the rotation of circles and letters.

```
<animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive"
repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
values="
    0, 56.13, 106.87;
    360, 56.13, 106.87"
additive="sum" />
```

3. We find the coordinates of the center of rotation of the letters using the getBBox () JS method

```
<script> 
  //Find the center of rotation of the letter A
  let bb = a1.getBBox();
console.log(bb.x+bb.width/2); 
console.log(bb.y+bb.height/2);
</script>
```

*The animation will start after clicking*

```css
text {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  fill:#6E6E6E;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="190px" height="190px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" version="1.1">
 <defs> 
  </defs>
  <g id="common">
  <g transform="translate(-27.970238,-63.089294)">
    <circle cx="102.9" cy="138.0" r="75" fill="#faa"/> 
    <path   d="m163.7 175.2-121.5 0 60.8-105.2z" fill="#fea"/>
   
   
          <!-- Spiral -->
    <path  d="m101.3 136.5c1.1 2-2.1 2.5-3.3 1.9-3.2-1.7-2.6-6.2-0.5-8.4 3.7-4.1 10.2-2.9 13.6 0.9 5 5.6 3.3 14.3-2.3 18.8-7.4 6-18.4 3.7-23.9-3.6-7-9.2-4.1-22.5 5-29.1 11-8 26.6-4.4 34.3 6.4 9 12.8 4.8 30.7-7.8 39.4-14.6 10-34.8 5.2-44.6-9.2-11.1-16.4-5.6-39 10.6-49.7 18.2-12.1 43.1-6 54.9 11.9 13.1 19.9 6.4 47.2-13.3 60.1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke:#6E6E6E">
      
    </path>
    <g id="La">
    <circle cx="55.9" cy="108.0" r="12.9" fill="#efa"/>
        <text id="a1"  x="51" y="112">
          A  
        </text> 
           <!-- Animation of the rotation of the letter `A` -->
         <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 56.13, 106.87;360, 56.13, 106.87" additive="sum" /> 
    </g>
    <g>
    <circle cx="153.7" cy="110.3" r="12.9" fill="#efa"/>
    <text id="b1" xml:space="preserve" x="114" y="116" >
        B
    </text> 
        <!-- Animation of the rotation of the letter `B` -->
       <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 153.7, 110.3;360, 153.7, 110.3" additive="sum" /> 
  </g> 
  <g>
  <circle cx="105.2" cy="192.5" r="12.9" fill="#efa"   />
    <text id="c1" x="100" y="198"  >
    C
  </text> 
       <!-- Animation of the rotation of the letter `C`   -->
       <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 104.93, 193.46;360, 104.93, 193.46" additive="sum" /> 
    </g>
   </g>  
  </g>  
      <!-- Animating the rotation of the entire shape   -->
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#common" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 75.74, 74.91;-360, 75.74, 74.91" additive="sum" />   
</svg> 
<script> 
  //Find the center of rotation of the letter A
  let bb = a1.getBBox();
console.log(bb.x+bb.width/2); 
console.log(bb.y+bb.height/2);
</script>
```

**Example with adding animation of the ball movement in a spiral**

```css
text {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  fill:#6E6E6E;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="190px" height="190px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" version="1.1">
 <defs> 
  </defs>
  <g id="common">
  <g transform="translate(-27.970238,-63.089294)">
    <circle cx="102.9" cy="138.0" r="75" fill="#faa"/> 
    <path   d="m163.7 175.2-121.5 0 60.8-105.2z" fill="#fea"/>
   
       
   <path   d="m163.7 175.2-121.5 0 60.8-105.2z" fill="#fea"/>
      <!-- Spiral track (pink) -->
    <path id="track"  d="m101.3 136.5c1.1 2-2.1 2.5-3.3 1.9-3.2-1.7-2.6-6.2-0.5-8.4 3.7-4.1 10.2-2.9 13.6 0.9 5 5.6 3.3 14.3-2.3 18.8-7.4 6-18.4 3.7-23.9-3.6-7-9.2-4.1-22.5 5-29.1 11-8 26.6-4.4 34.3 6.4 9 12.8 4.8 30.7-7.8 39.4-14.6 10-34.8 5.2-44.6-9.2-11.1-16.4-5.6-39 10.6-49.7 18.2-12.1 43.1-6 54.9 11.9 13.1 19.9 6.4 47.2-13.3 60.1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#FFAAAA"/>
          <!-- Spiral -->
    <path  stroke-dasharray="0,432" d="m101.3 136.5c1.1 2-2.1 2.5-3.3 1.9-3.2-1.7-2.6-6.2-0.5-8.4 3.7-4.1 10.2-2.9 13.6 0.9 5 5.6 3.3 14.3-2.3 18.8-7.4 6-18.4 3.7-23.9-3.6-7-9.2-4.1-22.5 5-29.1 11-8 26.6-4.4 34.3 6.4 9 12.8 4.8 30.7-7.8 39.4-14.6 10-34.8 5.2-44.6-9.2-11.1-16.4-5.6-39 10.6-49.7 18.2-12.1 43.1-6 54.9 11.9 13.1 19.9 6.4 47.2-13.3 60.1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#6E6E6E">
       <!-- Spiral animation -->
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" dur="10s" values="0,432;432,0;0,432" fill="freeze" />
    </path> 
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#6E6E6E">
       <!-- Ball movement in a spiral clockwise -->
    <animateMotion id="forwards"
      begin="svg1.click;back.end"
      dur="5s" >
      <mpath xlink:href="#track" />
    </animateMotion> 
       <!-- Ball movement in a spiral counterclockwise -->
      <animateMotion
           id="back"
           dur="5s"
           begin="forwards.end"
           repeatCount="1"
           keyPoints="1;0"
           keyTimes="0;1"
           calcMode="linear"
           rotate="auto"
           fill="freeze" > 
    <mpath xlink:href="#track" />
    </animateMotion> 
   </circle>    
    
    <g id="La">
    <circle cx="55.9" cy="108.0" r="12.9" fill="#efa"/>
        <text  x="51" y="112"> A  </text> 
         <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 55.9, 108;360, 55.9, 108" additive="sum" /> 
    </g>
    <g>
    <circle cx="153.7" cy="110.3" r="12.9" fill="#efa"/>
    <text xml:space="preserve" x="114" y="116" >
        B
    </text> 
       <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 153.7, 110.3;360, 153.7, 110.3" additive="sum" /> 
  </g> 
  <g>
  <circle cx="105.2" cy="192.5" r="12.9" fill="#efa"   />
    <text x="100" y="198"  > C
</text> 
       <!-- Animation of the rotation of the letter `C`   -->
       <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 105.2, 192.5;360, 105.2, 192.5" additive="sum" /> 
    </g>
   </g>  
  </g>  
      <!-- Animating the rotation of the entire shape   -->
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#common" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  
        values="0, 75.38, 75;-360, 75.38, 75" additive="sum" />   
</svg>
```