# SVG Path rotation center

Tags: css, svg

please help me.
I have a SVG image. I need to animate many objects from this SVG.
But provides animation objects move is unclear on what axis. I need to object rotate around its axis.

Video screen: http://dropix.net/view/1411265678541e348e45f2d/

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes svg_atom_1 {
  0% {
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
.element-atom-1 {
    -webkit-animation: svg_atom_1 13s linear infinite;
    animation: svg_atom_1 3s linear infinite;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="320" viewBox="0 0 960 320">
<path class="element-clock" fill="#ED1E79" d="M485 90h2v7h-2zM525.07 99.488l1.369.889-4.444 6.845-1.369-.889zM552.711 128.25l.853 1.392-6.958 4.263-.853-1.392zM554.365 205.887l-.819 1.41-7.056-4.1.819-1.41zM526.35 235.354l-1.396.845-4.224-6.982 1.396-.845zM486.872 245.342l-1.631.033-.166-8.159 1.631-.033zM448.369 236.372l-1.494-.658 3.29-7.468 1.494.658zM418.988 206.991l-.69-1.479 7.394-3.452.69 1.479zM408.441 168.492l.048-1.631 8.157.239-.048 1.631zM418.398 129.659l.852-1.39 6.957 4.265-.852 1.39zM446.366 101.147l1.375-.877 4.388 6.881-1.375.877zM564.358 167.014l-.017 1.633-8.16-.087.017-1.633z"/>
<path fill="#FF7BAC" d="M485.867 86.432"/>
<path opacity=".6" fill="#FBB03B" d="M486 86v87l39.443 64.233s42.257-20.391 41.319-69.906c.001 0-.093-73.445-80.762-81.327z"/><circle fill="#0cc" stroke="#0cc" stroke-width="1.558" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="485.674" cy="167.864" r="50.004"/><g fill="#666766">
<path class="element-clock-2" d="M556.291 183.288l.363-1.702 5.116 1.092-.363 1.702zM554.28 190.604l.537-1.656 4.976 1.614-.537 1.656zM551.463 197.599l.707-1.59 4.78 2.126-.707 1.59zM543.784 210.531l1.025-1.407 4.228 3.081-1.025 1.407zM538.99 216.323l1.168-1.295 3.883 3.502-1.168 1.295zM533.599 221.605l1.293-1.163 3.498 3.889-1.293 1.163zM527.665 226.295l1.41-1.023 3.069 4.233-1.41 1.023zM514.518 233.676l1.59-.711 2.134 4.772-1.59.711zM507.458 236.304l1.655-.538 1.617 4.973-1.655.538zM500.109 238.136l1.705-.363 1.09 5.115-1.705.363zM492.673 239.234l1.732-.181.543 5.203-1.732.181zM477.605 239.054l1.732.181-.543 5.203-1.732-.181zM470.18 237.775l1.703.363-1.091 5.116-1.703-.363zM462.933 235.745l1.655.538-1.618 4.974-1.655-.538zM455.912 232.976l1.594.711-2.131 4.777-1.594-.711zM442.944 225.278l1.409 1.022-3.072 4.233-1.409-1.022zM437.163 220.444l1.295 1.163-3.495 3.891-1.295-1.163zM557.583 175.896l.182-1.729 5.203.547-.182 1.729zM427.216 209.122l1.023 1.407-4.229 3.076-1.023-1.407zM419.822 195.986l.708 1.589-4.777 2.127-.708-1.589zM417.188 188.931l.535 1.657-4.979 1.608-.535-1.657zM415.338 181.617l.362 1.702-5.114 1.088-.362-1.702zM414.241 174.129l.182 1.729-5.201.546-.182-1.729zM414.421 159.06l-.182 1.73-5.201-.546.182-1.73zM415.687 151.623l-.362 1.704-5.114-1.088.362-1.704zM417.729 144.367l-.535 1.657-4.974-1.606.535-1.657zM419.818 138.965l.708-1.588-4.776-2.132-.709 1.595zM428.218 124.402l-1.024 1.408-4.232-3.076 1.024-1.408zM433.027 118.605l-1.164 1.292-3.887-3.502 1.164-1.292zM438.441 113.332l-1.295 1.165-3.498-3.888 1.295-1.165zM444.331 108.667l-1.409 1.021-3.069-4.235 1.409-1.021zM457.476 101.299l-1.594.708-2.124-4.781 1.594-.708zM464.563 98.657l-1.654.539-1.621-4.974 1.654-.539zM471.877 96.828l-1.703.362-1.089-5.116 1.703-.362zM479.347 95.748l-1.731.184-.552-5.2 1.731-.184zM557.768 160.835l-.182-1.73 5.201-.546.182 1.73zM556.672 153.363l-.363-1.704 5.114-1.09.363 1.704zM554.813 146.033l-.537-1.657 4.976-1.613.537 1.657zM551.48 137.377l.708 1.588 4.779-2.125-.707-1.595zM544.839 125.832l-1.025-1.408 4.228-3.078 1.025 1.408zM540.148 119.917l-1.168-1.292 3.878-3.506 1.168 1.292zM534.882 114.501l-1.293-1.165 3.501-3.885 1.293 1.165zM529.04 109.707l-1.41-1.021 3.067-4.234 1.41 1.021zM516.11 102.015l-1.589-.708 2.128-4.778 1.589.708zM509.086 99.235l-1.654-.539 1.621-4.976 1.654.539zM501.82 97.148l-1.705-.362 1.088-5.118 1.705.362zM431.844 215.055l1.164 1.295-3.89 3.497-1.164-1.295zM494.407 95.93l-1.731-.184.551-5.203 1.731.184z"/></g><g stroke-width="2" fill="none"><ellipse stroke="#66899A" cx="481.409" cy="170.426" rx="20.336" ry="149.132"/><ellipse transform="matrix(-.913 -.407 .407 -.913 851.879 521.925)" stroke="#E1D85D" cx="481.409" cy="170.426" rx="149.132" ry="20.336"/><ellipse transform="matrix(.913 -.407 .407 .913 -27.699 210.541)" stroke="#80A3CF" cx="481.409" cy="170.426" rx="149.132" ry="20.336"/></g><circle fill="#66899A" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" cx="497.508" cy="78.931" r="14.405"/>
<path class="element-atom-1" fill="#E5D015" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M555.479 200.33h5.568v-4.019c4.071-.985 6.582-3.812 6.582-7.565 0-3.842-2.041-6.195-6.825-7.868-1.756-.639-3.786-1.476-3.786-2.225 0-.985 1.384-1.137 2.207-1.137 2.407 0 3.947.741 4.869 1.183l1.059.507.336-1.116 1.32-4.962-.733-.346c-.976-.459-2.537-1.033-4.842-1.23v-3.335h-5.568v3.731c-3.866 1.005-6.249 3.741-6.249 7.334 0 4.632 3.909 6.54 7.316 7.688 2.894.976 3.295 1.681 3.295 2.294 0 .912-1.314 1.32-2.615 1.32-2.536 0-4.644-.945-5.671-1.509l-1.098-.6-1.604 6.267v.001l.658.363c1.485.822 3.674 1.401 5.782 1.591v3.633z" /><g fill="#80A3CF" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2">
<path d="M387.995 214.209c-8.832 0-15.991 5.506-15.991 12.301 0 3.331 1.725 6.36 4.524 8.574-.162 2.258-.706 5.021-2.281 6.51 3.134 0 6.337-1.963 8.362-3.498 1.683.463 3.493.716 5.385.716 8.832 0 15.991-5.503 15.991-12.301.001-6.796-7.158-12.302-15.99-12.302zM408.251 227.708c1.346-1.798 2.116-3.89 2.116-6.119 0-6.795-7.159-12.301-15.991-12.301-3.887 0-7.45 1.068-10.22 2.839 1.304-.246 2.667-.379 4.069-.379 9.511 0 17.221 6.059 17.221 13.531 0 2.945-1.193 5.673-3.228 7.89 2.02 1.535 5.228 3.503 8.362 3.503-2.228-2.115-2.388-6.804-2.329-8.964z"/></g>
<path fill="#DF5C4D" d="M536.5 137.833v61l-52 28.5-51-28.5v-61l51-28.5z"/>
<path fill="#BC4A3D" d="M530.5 141.387v53.893l-45.942 25.179-45.058-25.179v-53.893l45.058-25.18z"/><text transform="translate(456.5 186.333)" fill="#fff" font-family="'PTMono-Bold'" font-size="48">VS</text>
...
...
...
</svg>
```

Comment: It's a pity that FireFox **sucks** again in this case. In other browsers you can still use `transform-origin: 50%;` to center the origin of transforming but FireFox requires the unit to be  **absolute** not relative. So unless you know the exact absolute value of the center point, you can still use `transform-origin` with absolute unit.

Comment: just found out that IE does not support CSS transform on SVG element. So it even sucks more compared to what FireFox sucks. So the solution is try using pure SVG transform and animate (although they are both not powerful as CSS equivalents).

Comment: CSS `transform` not well support, you may want to [write your own coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089341/how-to-keep-text-orientation-unchanged-during-rotation-in-svg/25097447#25097447)