# Rotating SVG mask

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm struggling to find a way to rotate this SVG mask so that it rotates from within the center. In other words, I'm aiming for a spinning effect that will be on infinite loop. Also, I can't figure out why it will not rotate in Firefox. Any ideas?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbhood24/0ojspoc8/)

HTML:

```
<body class="home">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <svg version="1.1" id="first-ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%" height="100%"  xml:space="preserve">
      <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
          <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" class="first-ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 241.5 242" xml:space="preserve">
            <g class ="first-ring-path">
              <g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M118.4,237.5c-8.5,0-16.9-0.9-25.1-2.7c-2.8-0.6-4.6-3.4-3.9-6.2c0.6-2.8,3.4-4.5,6.2-3.9
                  c7.5,1.6,15.2,2.5,22.9,2.5c20.7,0,40.7-6,58-17.3c2.4-1.6,5.6-0.9,7.2,1.5c1.6,2.4,0.9,5.6-1.5,7.2
                  C163.1,230.9,141.1,237.5,118.4,237.5z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path   d="M192.5,209.2c-1.4,0-2.8-0.6-3.9-1.7c-1.9-2.1-1.7-5.4,0.4-7.3c3.9-3.5,7.5-7.3,10.9-11.3
                  c1.8-2.2,5.1-2.5,7.3-0.7s2.5,5.1,0.7,7.3c-3.6,4.4-7.7,8.6-11.9,12.4C195,208.7,193.7,209.2,192.5,209.2z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M214.6,181.9c-0.9,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.7c-2.5-1.4-3.3-4.6-1.9-7.1c9.3-16,14.1-34.3,14.1-52.9
                  c0-4.9-0.3-9.8-1-14.5c-0.4-2.8,1.6-5.4,4.4-5.8c2.8-0.4,5.4,1.6,5.8,4.4c0.7,5.2,1.1,10.6,1.1,15.9c0,20.4-5.4,40.5-15.5,58.1
                  C218.1,181,216.4,181.9,214.6,181.9z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M224.7,94.1c-2.2,0-4.3-1.4-4.9-3.7c-2.3-7.7-5.6-15.1-9.6-22.1c-1.4-2.5-0.6-5.6,1.9-7.1
                  c2.5-1.4,5.6-0.6,7.1,1.9c4.4,7.7,8,15.8,10.5,24.2c0.8,2.7-0.7,5.6-3.4,6.4C225.7,94,225.2,94.1,224.7,94.1z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M206.4,58.7c-1.5,0-3.1-0.7-4.1-2c-10.9-14.2-25.3-25.4-41.7-32.5c-2.6-1.1-3.8-4.2-2.7-6.8
                  s4.2-3.8,6.8-2.7c17.9,7.8,33.7,20.2,45.7,35.7c1.7,2.3,1.3,5.5-0.9,7.2C208.6,58.3,207.5,58.7,206.4,58.7z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M41,46.7c-1.3,0-2.7-0.5-3.7-1.6c-2-2-1.9-5.3,0.1-7.3C59.2,16.6,88,5,118.4,5c1.6,0,3.2,0,4.7,0.1
                  c2.9,0.1,5.1,2.5,5,5.4c-0.1,2.9-2.5,5.1-5.4,5c-1.4-0.1-2.9-0.1-4.3-0.1c-27.7,0-53.9,10.6-73.7,29.9
                  C43.6,46.2,42.3,46.7,41,46.7z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M7.5,119c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4,0c-2.8-0.2-5-2.7-4.8-5.5c0.3-4,0.8-8.1,1.5-12.1C6,88.3,10.5,75.7,17,64.2
                  c1.4-2.5,4.6-3.4,7-2c2.5,1.4,3.4,4.6,2,7c-5.9,10.5-10,21.9-12.1,33.9c-0.6,3.6-1.1,7.4-1.3,11C12.4,116.9,10.2,119,7.5,119z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path  d="M58.6,220c-1,0-1.9-0.3-2.8-0.8c-26.2-16.7-44.8-43.7-51.2-74c-0.6-2.8,1.2-5.5,4-6.1s5.5,1.2,6.1,4
                  c5.8,27.6,22.8,52.1,46.6,67.4c2.4,1.5,3.1,4.7,1.6,7.1C61.9,219.2,60.3,220,58.6,220z"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </mask>
    </svg>
    <rect id="rect" mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="5000px" height="5000px"/>
  </svg>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight:100;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}    
svg  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
svg mask rect {
    fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
svg > rect {
    fill: white;
    // -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
    // -moz-mask: url(#mask);
    // mask: url(#mask);
}
.first-ring-path{
    -moz-animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
    animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
}  
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinoff {
    0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinoff {
    0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Comment: CSS animation doesn't currently work on masks in Firefox (it's a known bug). SMIL should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I just posted the same coding to a [SMIL animation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012940/css-animation-and-animation-direction-not-working-in-ie11/38018319#38018319). Only 7 liners, both are based on a [old solution: How to Keep Text Orientation....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089341/how-to-keep-text-orientation-unchanged-during-rotation-in-svg/25097447#25097447)

**Edit:** Tested on latest FF v47 (June2016)

```js
var myPath = document.getElementById('pathRotate');
var i = 0;
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 30);

function myCallback() {
// Rotate the square by a small amount.
  if (i == 360) { i = 0}
  myPath.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ", 121,121)"); 
  ++i;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.home {
  background-image: url('../images/ontocore_home_background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.home-overlay {
  height: 4000;
  background-image: url('../images/ontocore_home_overlay.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

svg  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

svg mask rect {
    fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
svg > rect {
    fill: white;
    // -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
    // -moz-mask: url(#mask);
    // mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<body class="home">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <svg version="1.1" id="first-ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="100%" height="100%"  xml:space="preserve">

    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" class="first-ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 241.5 242" xml:space="preserve">
      <g id="pathRotate" class ="first-ring-path">
        <g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M118.4,237.5c-8.5,0-16.9-0.9-25.1-2.7c-2.8-0.6-4.6-3.4-3.9-6.2c0.6-2.8,3.4-4.5,6.2-3.9
              c7.5,1.6,15.2,2.5,22.9,2.5c20.7,0,40.7-6,58-17.3c2.4-1.6,5.6-0.9,7.2,1.5c1.6,2.4,0.9,5.6-1.5,7.2
              C163.1,230.9,141.1,237.5,118.4,237.5z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path   d="M192.5,209.2c-1.4,0-2.8-0.6-3.9-1.7c-1.9-2.1-1.7-5.4,0.4-7.3c3.9-3.5,7.5-7.3,10.9-11.3
              c1.8-2.2,5.1-2.5,7.3-0.7s2.5,5.1,0.7,7.3c-3.6,4.4-7.7,8.6-11.9,12.4C195,208.7,193.7,209.2,192.5,209.2z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M214.6,181.9c-0.9,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.7c-2.5-1.4-3.3-4.6-1.9-7.1c9.3-16,14.1-34.3,14.1-52.9
              c0-4.9-0.3-9.8-1-14.5c-0.4-2.8,1.6-5.4,4.4-5.8c2.8-0.4,5.4,1.6,5.8,4.4c0.7,5.2,1.1,10.6,1.1,15.9c0,20.4-5.4,40.5-15.5,58.1
              C218.1,181,216.4,181.9,214.6,181.9z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M224.7,94.1c-2.2,0-4.3-1.4-4.9-3.7c-2.3-7.7-5.6-15.1-9.6-22.1c-1.4-2.5-0.6-5.6,1.9-7.1
              c2.5-1.4,5.6-0.6,7.1,1.9c4.4,7.7,8,15.8,10.5,24.2c0.8,2.7-0.7,5.6-3.4,6.4C225.7,94,225.2,94.1,224.7,94.1z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M206.4,58.7c-1.5,0-3.1-0.7-4.1-2c-10.9-14.2-25.3-25.4-41.7-32.5c-2.6-1.1-3.8-4.2-2.7-6.8
              s4.2-3.8,6.8-2.7c17.9,7.8,33.7,20.2,45.7,35.7c1.7,2.3,1.3,5.5-0.9,7.2C208.6,58.3,207.5,58.7,206.4,58.7z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M41,46.7c-1.3,0-2.7-0.5-3.7-1.6c-2-2-1.9-5.3,0.1-7.3C59.2,16.6,88,5,118.4,5c1.6,0,3.2,0,4.7,0.1
              c2.9,0.1,5.1,2.5,5,5.4c-0.1,2.9-2.5,5.1-5.4,5c-1.4-0.1-2.9-0.1-4.3-0.1c-27.7,0-53.9,10.6-73.7,29.9
              C43.6,46.2,42.3,46.7,41,46.7z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M7.5,119c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4,0c-2.8-0.2-5-2.7-4.8-5.5c0.3-4,0.8-8.1,1.5-12.1C6,88.3,10.5,75.7,17,64.2
              c1.4-2.5,4.6-3.4,7-2c2.5,1.4,3.4,4.6,2,7c-5.9,10.5-10,21.9-12.1,33.9c-0.6,3.6-1.1,7.4-1.3,11C12.4,116.9,10.2,119,7.5,119z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path  d="M58.6,220c-1,0-1.9-0.3-2.8-0.8c-26.2-16.7-44.8-43.7-51.2-74c-0.6-2.8,1.2-5.5,4-6.1s5.5,1.2,6.1,4
              c5.8,27.6,22.8,52.1,46.6,67.4c2.4,1.5,3.1,4.7,1.6,7.1C61.9,219.2,60.3,220,58.6,220z"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      </svg>
    </mask>
  <
</svg>
    <rect id="rect" mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="5000px" height="5000px"/>
  </svg>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

for rotation from center add

transform-origin: 50% 50%;

as follows:

```
.first-ring-path{
      -moz-animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
        animation:spin 20s infinite linear;
         transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
```

Comment: Does that really work? [I was pretty sure CSS animation of mask contents didn't.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118710)

Comment: Works in Chrome...Sorry, I didn't build a cross-browser package.

Comment: Yes, @RobertLongson is correct about CSS animations not working in Firefox for masks. Do you think there's a jQuery alternative that would have better browser support?

Comment: This can most likely be accomplished with Javascript. Do you want to give it a try?