# css animation and animation-direction not working in IE11

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to show animated dashed lines in an SVG path.
Path is generated dynamically using d3 and animation can be in both the directions. Its working in all browsers except in IE. [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/7r0mnnfj/2/)
My issue is similar to [SVG animation is not working on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-not-working-on-ie-11) . But I couldn't get the solution from there.

```
<path id="pathOriginal" class="animation" style="animation-direction:reverse" d="M535,73C33.75,73 33.75,-20 -467.5,-20" stroke="red" stroke-width="1.5px" fill="none">
```

```
    @keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    }
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
.animation {
    stroke-dasharray: 4;
    stroke-dashoffset: 4;
    animation: dash 50s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: dash 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last resort is to use some javascript magic!

```js
var myPath = document.getElementById('pathOriginal');

var i = 1000;
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 20);

function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
  if (i == 0) { i = 1000}
  myPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', i);
  --i;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g transform="translate(200,200)">
<path id="pathOriginal" class="animation" style="animation-direction:reverse" d="M535,73C33.75,73 33.75,-20 -467.5,-20" stroke="red" stroke-width="1.5px" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="4">
</path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If solution works, do click on the 'accept' checkmark so that future readers can reuse this solution in similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

IE don't support CSS animations on all SVG elements.
you have to modify the inline attributes of the SVG elements

Comment: Is there any alternate way to show the path like animated?

Comment: Greensock's drawSVG comes with a subscription cost (plus learning curve) vs. 7 lines of coding below to replace CSS animation,